# How do you use pyodbc in Azure Machine Learning Workbench

Tags: docker, pyodbc, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to use pyodbc to import a dataframe in Azure ML Workbench. This works in local runs, but not for docker. It fails when trying to establish a connection to the SQL Server, because the driver is not present.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

Error Message:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
>   lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

When searching for a solution i found that i could put these lines in the docker file

> ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
>
> RUN apt-get update
>
> RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev
>
> RUN apt install unixodbc-bin -y
>
> RUN apt-get clean -y

However I'm new to docker, and cannot figure out where to put these lines in the ML Workbench. It seems the docker file is generated through **docker.compute** and **conda_dependencies.yml**, but nothing similar to the lines above can be found in either of those or anywere else in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can build docker image with dependencies you need and specify your image name inside the docker.compute file:

```
baseDockerImage:<your docker image name>
```

I created [azml_pyodbc image](https://hub.docker.com/r/aksanakuzmitskaya/azml_pyodbc/), 
you can try to use it with:

```
baseDockerImage: "aksanakuzmitskaya/azml_pyodbc:firsttry"
DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
```

Comment: When I add this line "DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'"  in docker.compute, it doesn't work, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In docker.compute only baseDockerImage is specified. DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' is added in the python script where SQL server is going to be established. ex: cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)