# Why does my login to MS SQL with AzureML dataprep using Windows authentication fail?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-authentication

I tried connecting to a MS SQL database using [`azureml.dataprep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-dataprep/azureml.dataprep?view=azure-dataprep-py) in an Azure Notebook, as outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-load-data#load-sql-data, using [MSSqlDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-dataprep/azureml.dataprep.mssqldatasource?view=azure-dataprep-py), using code of the form

```
import azureml.dataprep as dprep

secret = dprep.register_secret(value="[SECRET-PASSWORD]", id="[SECRET-ID]")

ds = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(server_name="[SERVER-NAME]",
                       database_name="[DATABASE-NAME], [PORT]",
                       user_name="[DATABASE-USERNAME]",
                       password=secret)
```

Setting `[DATABASE-USERNAME]` equal to `MYWINDOWSDOMAIN\\MYWINDOWSUSERNAME` and the password `[SECRET-PASSWORD]` coinciding with my Windows password (i.e. trying to use Windows authentication).

After firing a query with

```
dataflow = dprep.read_sql(ds, "SELECT top 100 * FROM [dbo].[MYTABLE]")
dataflow.head(5)
```

I get

> ExecutionError: Login failed.

I could connect to other databases without Windows Authentication fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to access database with other database tool? Like `datagrip`?

Comment: Hi! Would like to stick to `dataprep` (I can access the db with an ODBC driver) but wanted to use AzureML tools here.

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings of the SQL Database in Azure?

Comment: Should be fine (?) <= I can ping `[SERVER-NAME]` at least.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [SQL server authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-through-sql-server-authentication) as a workaround/alternative solution to connect to that db (the same `dataflow`  syntax will work):

```
import azureml.dataprep as dprep
secret = dprep.register_secret(value="[SECRET-PASSWORD]", id="[SECRET-ID]")

ds = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(server_name="[SERVER-NAME],[PORT]",
               database_name="[DATABASE-NAME]",
               user_name="[DATABASE-USERNAME]",
               password=secret)
```

**Note that the usage of `dataprep` is deprecated, `sqlalchemy` can be used instead with:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def mssql_engine(user = "[DATABASE-USERNAME]", 
                 password = "[SECRET-PASSWORD]", 
                 host = "[SERVER-NAME],[PORT]",
                 db = "[DATABASE-NAME]"):
    engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{host}/{db}?driver=SQL+Server')
    return engine

query = "SELECT ..."

df = pd.read_sql(query, mssql_engine())
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the MS Doc on `MSSQLDataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-dataprep/azureml.dataprep.mssqldatasource?view=azure-dataprep-py). `MSSQLDataSource` instances have a property, `credentials_type` which defaults to `SERVER`. Try explicitly setting this to `WINDOWS` before you do your query. Also, the port should be specified together with the server name.

```
import azureml.dataprep as dprep

windows_domain = 'localhost'
windows_user = 'my_user'
windows_password = 'my_password'

secret = dprep.register_secret(value=windows_password, id="password")

ds = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(server_name="localhost",
                   database_name="myDb",
                   user_name=f'{windows_domain}\{windows_user}',
                   password=secret)

ds.credentials_type = dprep.DatabaseAuthType.WINDOWS

dataflow = dprep.read_sql(ds, "SELECT top 100 * FROM [dbo].[MYTABLE]")
dataflow.head(5)
```

Comment: Aw, thanks but that still fails with `ExecutionError: Could not connect to specified database.` In the end I gave up (see my own answer on how I "solved" this)

Comment: @DavideFiocco I slightly modified my answer above. I can successfully use that to windows authenticate / query a sql express database on my local PC. I don't have a full domain to work on but the local windows auth works as expected.

Comment: Actually after some further testing, it seems the windows creds specified are irrelevant to the server authentication. The query fails if no windows creds are provided, but providing invalid creds makes no difference - the authentication uses the windows user that is running your python process. I'm not sure how this would work from linux - it seems the support for windows authentication is quite limited.